# Execute MySQL commands in Java ProcessBuilder on Windows

Tags: java, mysql, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute some MySQL commands from Java `ProcessBuilder` on WINDOWS and I faced some problems. At the moment, what I want to do is to show databases but in the near future I'm going to use dump etc. So this is the way it should be.

Here is my code:

```
try {

//  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:/\"Program files\"/MySQL/\"MySQL Server 8.0\"/bin/mysql -uroot -pMYPASS -e \"show databases;\""); 
//  IT DIDN'T WORK EITHER.

    ProcessBuilder coolBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "C://\"Program files\"/MySQL/\"MySQL Server 8.0\"/bin/mysql -u root -pMYPASS -e \"show databases;\""});
    Process process = coolBuilder.start();

    int errCode = process.waitFor();
    if (errCode != 0) {
        System.out.println("errCode = " + errCode);
        errorList.add(ErrorEnum.ERROR_OCCURED_WHILE_INSIDE_SHELL.toString());
    }

    for (String s : output(process.getErrorStream())) {
        if (!s.contains("Warning")) {
            errorList.add(s);
            return errorList;
        }
    }

    return output(process.getInputStream());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
C://Program files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Usage: C://Program files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup



...

errCode = 1
```

Any suggestions where I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem.  I suspect you might have an odd character in your password that the Windows command prompt isn't keen on.

Have you tried to execute the `mysql` executable directly rather than via `cmd.exe`, i.e. by using something like the following?

```
        ProcessBuilder coolBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"C://Program files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql", "-u", "root", "-pMYPASS", "-e", "show databases;"});
        Process process = coolBuilder.start();
```

This way you don't need to quote all of the arguments.